# Start a BPM process from the ESB (WSO2-Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0)

Tags: wso2, esb, business-process-management

I would like to understand which in the best practice in wso2 to start a bpm process from the esb.

Basically I would need to define a service that starts a bpm process as soon as it receives an amqp message.

For the implementation of the service, I am refering to this https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ESB+as+a+RabbitMQ+Message+Consumer 
that works as expected.

Now I am wondering which is the best practice to start the bpmn process from the ESB. Personally I would use an HTTPEndPoint to send the ReST POST "Start a Process Instance" (refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/BPMN+REST+API#BPMNRESTAPI-Processinstances).

Is it this the expected approach or is there a better integrated way?

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested approach is correct. BPMN process can be started using a REST call to the BPMN Rest api. Then the respective process will start and initiate a process instance. Make sure to send the correct data to the start resource.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/BPMN+REST+API#BPMNRESTAPI-StartaProcessInstance

Regards
Nandika